# Overlapping density plots in a ggtern ternary diagram

Tags: r, overlap, density-plot, ggtern

I have two datasets looking like the following:

#dataset 1

```
    structure(list(dataset1 = 1:86, x = c(24.22055, 24.61821, 24.60858, 
24.5963, 24.66904, 24.682, 24.74323, 24.84038, 25.02606, 25.00763, 
24.99861, 25.00901, 24.99273, 24.98789, 24.99308, 24.97615, 24.9572, 
24.95962, 24.93451, 25.08111, 24.97653, 24.92734, 24.96208, 25.03111, 
25.00242, 24.95385, 24.99345, 25.03311, 24.93516, 24.95163, 24.94859, 
25.07071, 25.15814, 25.22433, 25.3163, 25.22823, 25.34902, 25.4118, 
25.40885, 25.35868, 25.34709, 25.24046, 25.31097, 25.32868, 25.41141, 
24.92474, 24.90951, 24.9927, 25.0052, 24.94954, 25.15449, 25.10164, 
25.03112, 24.97345, 25.03352, 25.11059, 25.05391, 25.05766, 25.06176, 
25.17039, 25.17868, 25.1053, 25.0568, 25.08028, 25.137, 25.36559, 
25.06363, 25.26306, 25.16708, 25.14826, 25.06046, 24.99418, 25.19738, 
25.20072, 25.24073, 25.18705, 25.18142, 25.16747, 25.1235, 25.38767, 
25.37099, 25.30558, 25.35074, 25.33528, 25.32482, 25.32328), 
    y = c(22.25462, 21.88752, 21.89172, 21.88356, 21.86319, 21.80782, 
    21.7451, 21.70914, 21.68861, 21.66829, 21.67942, 21.67475, 
    21.67994, 21.67462, 21.67405, 21.67494, 21.66842, 21.65091, 
    21.6657, 21.68427, 21.66878, 21.6711, 21.66772, 21.63123, 
    21.64916, 21.65174, 21.65686, 21.63292, 21.64039, 21.53591, 
    21.64633, 21.62177, 21.61304, 21.60609, 21.594, 21.60413, 
    21.59069, 21.58264, 21.58277, 21.57736, 21.57457, 21.57674, 
    21.56562, 21.49258, 21.48584, 21.74852, 21.73081, 21.75594, 
    21.66646, 21.70782, 21.67075, 21.66456, 21.64514, 21.65763, 
    21.66863, 21.64658, 21.63672, 21.62677, 21.65441, 21.61994, 
    21.61754, 21.65159, 21.62676, 21.61157, 21.60181, 21.65121, 
    21.61303, 21.61424, 21.61419, 21.6258, 21.59797, 21.61477, 
    21.5879, 21.58918, 21.61834, 21.56725, 21.61358, 21.61456, 
    21.57619, 21.592, 21.58095, 21.52847, 21.57284, 21.56755, 
    21.56847, 21.49455), z = c(53.52483, 53.49427, 53.49971, 
    53.52014, 53.46777, 53.51018, 53.51168, 53.45048, 53.28533, 
    53.32408, 53.32197, 53.31623, 53.32733, 53.33749, 53.33287, 
    53.34891, 53.37439, 53.38947, 53.39978, 53.23462, 53.35469, 
    53.40156, 53.3702, 53.33767, 53.34843, 53.39441, 53.34969, 
    53.33398, 53.42445, 53.51247, 53.40507, 53.30752, 53.22882, 
    53.16958, 53.0897, 53.16764, 53.06029, 53.00556, 53.00838, 
    53.06396, 53.07834, 53.1828, 53.12341, 53.17874, 53.10275, 
    53.32674, 53.35968, 53.25136, 53.32834, 53.34264, 53.17476, 
    53.2338, 53.32374, 53.36892, 53.29785, 53.24283, 53.30937, 
    53.31556, 53.28384, 53.20967, 53.20378, 53.24311, 53.31644, 
    53.30816, 53.26118, 52.9832, 53.32334, 53.1227, 53.21872, 
    53.22594, 53.34158, 53.39105, 53.21472, 53.2101, 53.14093, 
    53.2457, 53.205, 53.21797, 53.30031, 53.02033, 53.04806, 
    53.16595, 53.07643, 53.09717, 53.10672, 53.18217)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-86L))
```

#dataset2

```
    structure(list(dataset2 = 1:16, x1 = c(24.702, 24.64061, 24.64624, 
24.699, 24.68064, 24.65854, 24.75148, 24.58633, 24.73463, 24.59992, 
24.65293, 24.60753, 24.62394, 25.3416, 24.71006, 24.67719), y1 = c(21.87799, 
21.89606, 21.9034, 21.8859, 21.89083, 21.90291, 21.8491, 21.93269, 
21.87262, 21.87465, 21.90029, 21.87801, 21.87661, 21.64635, 21.83719, 
21.90565), z1 = c(53.42002, 53.46333, 53.45036, 53.4151, 53.42853, 
53.43855, 53.39942, 53.48098, 53.39274, 53.52543, 53.44677, 53.51446, 
53.49945, 53.01205, 53.45276, 53.41716)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

I have written a code to plot kernel density contours according to the ggtern package.

```
# density plot for dataset 1 
plot1 <- ggtern(data = test,aes(x=x, y=y, z=z))
plot1+ stat_density_tern(geom="polygon",
                     aes(fill  = ..level..,
                         alpha = ..level..)) +
theme_rgbw() +
labs(title = "Example Density/Contour Plot")    +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightblue",high = "blue")  +
guides(color = "none", fill = "none", alpha = "none")+
scale_T_continuous (limits = c(0.225,0.215))+
scale_L_continuous (limits= c(0.255,0.245))+
scale_R_continuous (limits = c(0.53,0.54))


# density plot for dataset 2 
plot2 <- ggtern(data = test2,aes(x=x1, y=y1, z=z1))
plot2 + stat_density_tern(geom="polygon",
                     aes(fill  = ..level..,
                         alpha = ..level..)) +
theme_rgbw() +
labs(title = "Example Density/Contour Plot")    +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightgreen",high = "green")  +
guides(color = "none", fill = "none", alpha = "none")+
scale_T_continuous (limits = c(0.225,0.215))+
scale_L_continuous (limits= c(0.255,0.245))+
scale_R_continuous (limits = c(0.53,0.54))
```

[image]

The next step I would like to do is to overlap plot1 with plot2. I was wondering if anyone knows how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: You should post your data using `dput(...)`. See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `ggplot` and its friends expect data in long format. You can bind your two dataframes together with some additional variable to distinguish them, so you have a single long dataframe. Then map color/fill onto that new variable

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but I try to perform the kernel density estimation for each dataset before assigning the fill colors. If I combine data together, does that mean the kde is applied for all  rather than the individual?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is to add a column to both dataframes identifying the source of the data and then to combine then into 1 large data frame.
Then in the mapping definition define the "group" parameter.

```
#Add column to identify the data source
test1$id <- "Test1"
test2$id <- "Test2"

test2$z <- test2$z+0.2
test2$y <- test2$y+0.2
#combine both datasets into 1
names(test2)<-names(test1)
totalTest <- rbind(test1, test2)

#plot and group by the new ID column
plot1 <- ggtern(data = totalTest, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z, group=id, fill=id))
plot1+ stat_density_tern(geom="polygon",
                         aes(fill  = ..level..,
                             alpha = ..level..)) +
   theme_rgbw() +
   labs(title = "Example Density/Contour Plot")    +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightblue",high = "blue")  +
  guides(color = "none", fill = "none", alpha = "none") +
  scale_T_continuous (limits = c(0.225,0.215))+
  scale_L_continuous (limits= c(0.255,0.245))+
  scale_R_continuous (limits = c(0.53,0.54))
```